# Find the density $f_Y$ for $Y: = \sqrt{X+1}$

Tags: probability

> Let $X: Ω \to [-1, 1]$ be a uniformly distributed random variable,
> i.e. for $-1≤a≤b≤1$,
>
> $$P ({X∈ [a, b]}) = (b-a) / 2$$
>
> Find the density $f_Y$ for $Y: = \sqrt{X+1}$

**My idea:**

I wanna try it with the distribution function.

So $F_Y(t)=P(\sqrt{X+1}≤t)$

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Your $Y$ is $\sqrt{X+1}$, so why are you starting with $P(Y \le t) = P(|X| \le t)$?

Comment: is it now better?

Comment: Now solve for $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea.
$$P(\sqrt{X+1}\leq t)=P(X+1\leq t^2)=P(X\leq t^2-1)= \\ =\frac{1}{2}\int_{[-1,1]}\mathbb{I}_{\{x\leq t^2-1\}}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{[-1,t^2-1]}dx=\frac{1}{2}(t^2-1+1)=\frac{t^2}{2}$$
Now if $X=-1$ then $Z:=\sqrt{X+1}=0$ while if $X=1$ then $Z=\sqrt{2}$ so
$$f_Z(t)=t \ \ \ \ \ \ t \in [0,\sqrt{2}]$$
Indeed $f_Z\geq 0$ and
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}tdt=\frac{1}{2}(2-0)=1$$

Comment: thanks so much :)

Comment: one question..what is Z? Do you mean Y?

Comment: @Kev99 Yes. I called it $Z$

Comment: and why 1/2 in front of the integral?

Comment: @Kev99 It's the uniform density of $X$

Comment: because of this? : $$P ({X∈ [a, b]}) = (b-a) / 2$$

Comment: @Kev99 The density of a uniform rv $X : \Omega \to [c,d]$ is $1/(d-c)$

Comment: ok understood. thank you